# Inno setup enumerator

Tags: iis, inno-setup, enumerate

I'm trying to enumerate the Properties_ property of the IIsWebServer using the WbemScripting.SWbemLocator object.  My goal is to use PascalScript code to retrieve the server-bindings of a website.  In VBScript, I have the following code:

```
Dim site, binding, url
Set site = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1")
For Each binding In site.ServerBindings
    url = binding
    Exit For
Next
If Left(url, 1) = ":" Then
    url = "localhost" & url
End If
If Right(url, 1) Then
    url = Left(url, Len(url) - 1)
End If
Set site = Nothing
```

I wrote this code freehand so it may not be exact, but I would like to do it in PascalScript in a similar fashion.  The part I am stuck on is enumerating through the ServerBindings.  I have tried many things to get it to work and at the current point I'm at, I have the following PascalScript:

```
function GetWebSites() : Array of String;
var
    locatorObj, providerObj, nodeObj, appRoot: Variant;
    props : String;
begin
    locatorObj := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
    providerObj := locatorObj.ConnectServer(GetComputerNameString(), 'root/MicrosoftIISv2');
    nodeObj := providerObj.Get('IIsWebServer=''W3SVC/1''');

    props := nodeObj.Properties_;
    // How do I enumerate through the properties here?  Or, my actual goal is from this point how do I get the ServerBindings (or the first element in the ServerBindings array)?
```

end;

In JavaScript, to get the ServerBindings, you must us something similar to the following:

```
var e = new Enumerator(nodeObj.Properties_);
for (; ! e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
    var prop = e.item();
    if (prop.Name == 'ServerBindings') {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Inno code unfortunately does not support doing COM enumeration natively, but you can get support by using a helper DLL.  See [here](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=WMI) for details.

If you just want to access a known named property, though -- just do it.

```
nodeObj.ServerBindings
```